# Multi-part data with image and other parameters in AFNetworking 3.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I have a problem when uploading image with other parameters. With AFNetworking 3.0

com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data=<7b227374 61747573 223a2246 41494c55 5245222c 22737461 74757343 6f646522 3a353030 7d>, NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500)} I am getting

```
NSMutableDictionary *getUpdates= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
NSString*userID=@"3";
[getUpdates setObject:userID forKey:@"userId"];
[getUpdates setObject:phoneNumTF.text forKey:@"mobileNumber"];
[getUpdates setObject:nameTF.text forKey:@"name"];
[getUpdates setObject:workZipCodeTF.text forKey:@"work"];
[getUpdates setObject:homeZipCodeTF.text forKey:@"home"];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

[manager POST:kUpdateProfile_Post parameters:getUpdates constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:ImageData
                                name:@"files"
                            fileName:@"picture" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Here i Need to send like this data
picture:filename
 json:{ "name": "harish", "work": 92121, "userId": 3, "mobileNumber": 33663366, "home": "500025" }

Any help?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what error you are facing?

Comment: failed: internal server error (500)

Comment: Well, if it's a 500, then in most cases it is a server-side issue rather than the app. You should verify if some other client (android/web) is able to upload images.

Comment: Android side is completed. They are Successfully Implemented update profile

Comment: "{"status":"FAILURE","statusCode":500}", that's the response from your serveur (the data stuff you didn't serialized). Ask your server about what could be wrong. How is constructed `ImageData`? base64 encoding? Check the code from the Android side to see point any difference, try with the same image, check the param, the data, etc.

Comment: It seems it is server side error.

Comment: No it's not base64 encoding. But they are uploading with image path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// Dictionary that holds post parameters. You can set your post parameters that your server accepts or programmed to accept.

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString*userID = [def objectForKey:@"UserId"];
NSMutableDictionary *getUpdates= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[getUpdates setObject:userID forKey:@"userId"];
[getUpdates setObject:phoneNumTF.text forKey:@"mobileNumber"];
[getUpdates setObject:nameTF.text forKey:@"name"];
[getUpdates setObject:workZipCodeTF.text forKey:@"work"];
[getUpdates setObject:homeZipCodeTF.text forKey:@"home"];


[MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:true];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer]; // only needed if the server is not returning JSON; if web service returns JSON, remove this line


[manager POST:kUpdateProfile_Post parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:getUpdates options:0 error:&error];
    NSAssert(jsonData, @"Failure building JSON: %@", error);


    NSDictionary *jsonHeaders = @{@"Content-Disposition" : @"form-data; name=\"json\"",
                                  @"Content-Type"        : @"application/json"};
    [formData appendPartWithHeaders:jsonHeaders body:jsonData];

    if (ImageData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:ImageData name:@"picture"
                                fileName:@"image.jpg"
                                mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    }
} progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];
    NSLog(@"error appending part: %@", json);

    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:true];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:true];

}];
```

Finally I got with this code

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities,

- Might be you are sending sending some parameters name different
- Server developer doing something wrong at backend

Discuss this issue with him , ask him to debug each line when you made request.

Comment: picture:filename
 json:{
 "name": "harish", 
 "work": 92121,  
"userId": 3, 
 "mobileNumber": 33663366,  
"home": "500025"  
}

These are my parameters

Comment: {status code: 500, headers {
    "Content-Length" = 37;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Thu, 16 Feb 2017 12:44:38 GMT";
}}

Answer (score 0):

Check below things with your code:

1) Make sure **ImageData** shouldn't be **nil**.

2) Check the **mine type** with your server **mine type**. It may case that both are different.

3) Check the key name with your api name.

Comment: Send me api name. I will create a small demo for you.

Comment: picture:filename
 json:{ "name": "harish", "work": 92121, "userId": 3, "mobileNumber": 33663366, "home": "500025" }

I need to send like this